# How to make div size width depending on child element size

Tags: html, css

I want my menu width to be expandable depending on the menu item. On my example it takes 100% of the page, I would like to be juste the right size.

Here is my code and a [FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qsuwg/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <span>Menu 1</span>
    <span>Menu 2</span>
    <span>Menu 3</span>
    <span>Menu 4</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#menu span {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simply using `span` instead of `div`

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qsuwg/1/)

```
<span id="menu">
    <span>Menu 1</span>
    <span>Menu 2</span>
    <span>Menu 3</span>
    <span>Menu 4</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer but @Hiral's answer is actually a better answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `display:inline-block;` to `#menu`

```
#menu {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsuwg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`div`s are by default `block` elements. But you basically need your menu to be `inline`. So either make the `div` `display:inline-block` or enclose the menu in a `span` instead of `div`

Preferably this one:

```
#menu{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qsuwg/4/)**